# Pub get returns exit code 69

Tags: dart, mobile

I was trying to create Dart project when the command `pub get` returned error `Connection closed before full header was received exit code 69`. Do you have any idea why does this error appear?

[image: Here is a screenshot]

**pubspec.yaml**

[image: pubspec.yaml]

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: Are you using Flutter? What does `Flutter doctor` say?

Comment: @nvoigt No, I'm not using Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your pubspec.yaml file is not properly formatted.

We cannot really tell because you only pasted a screenshot and it's hard to make out whether there is any stray whitespace with just a screenshot.

You can use http://www.yamllint.com/ to validate your YAML file and get it corrected.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't help)